# How can I install ibunwind-setjmp0-dbg on ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver?

Tags: 18.04, arm

I am trying to install Pref tool on an ARM paltform (ODROID-XU4) running on ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver, below is a script of installing the necessary packages

```
odroid@odroid:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install flex bison libdw-dev libnewt-dev binutils-dev libaudit-dev libgtk2.0-dev libperl-dev libpython-dev libunwind-*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libunwind-dev' for glob 'libunwind-*'
Note, selecting 'libunwind-setjmp0-dbg' for glob 'libunwind-*'
Note, selecting 'libunwind-setjmp0-dev' for glob 'libunwind-*'
Note, selecting 'libunwind-setjmp0' for glob 'libunwind-*'
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.24.32-1ubuntu1).
libunwind-setjmp0 is already the newest version (1.2.1-8).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libunwind-setjmp0-dbg : Depends: libunwind-setjmp0 (= 1.1-2.2ubuntu3) 
but 1.2.1-8 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the output of apt-cache policy libunwind-setjmp0 libunwind-setjmp0-dbg is shown below

```
libunwind-setjmp0:
Installed: 1.2.1-8
Candidate: 1.2.1-8
Version table:
*** 1.2.1-8 500
500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main armhf Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1.1-2.2ubuntu3 500
    500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty/main armhf Packages
libunwind-setjmp0-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1-2.2ubuntu3
  Version table:
    1.1-2.2ubuntu3 500
    500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty/main armhf 
   Packages
   odroid@odroid:~/Desktop$
```

How can I solve the reported error ?

Comment: I can't find [libunwind-setjmp0-dbg](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&searchon=names&keywords=libunwind-setjmp0-dbg) in the repositories. Is it from a PPA?

Comment: libuwind_setjmp0 is from PPA. for the dbg one I'm not sure.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libunwind-setjmp0 libunwind-setjmp0-dbg`  to the question.